# Efeitos CSS não estão funcionando

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap

O código abaixo está funcional, as classes são adicionadas sem problemas, porém vejo que ao inspecionar os elementos, posso notar que a pagina, já carregada, contém as classes incluídas nos seus respectivos elementos, mas os efeitos não ocorrem.

Creio que seja porque o html está carregando antes ou algo do tipo.. alguém sabe como resolver?

*Obs: Sou iniciante no [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)*

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>


<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

         $("button").addClass("animated bounce");
  $(".text-primary").addClass("animated shake");
  $(".well").addClass("animated shake");


  $("#target3").addClass('fadeOut');


    });

    </script>


<!-- Only change code above this line. -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3 class="text-primary text-center">jQuery Playground</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>#left-well</h4>
      <div class="well" id="left-well">
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target1">#target1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target2">#target2</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target3">#target3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>#right-well</h4>
      <div class="well" id="right-well">
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target4">#target4</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target5">#target5</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default target" id="target6">#target6</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O código incluído está se a basear somente nas classes para animar, por isso é necessário que o css das classes seja mostrado também. O Jquery utilizado apenas adiciona classes css, fazendo nada mais.

Comment: favor disponibilizar o conteudo do arquivo styles.css

Comment: `Então, estou começando a pegar o jquery agora` e aí, ele é tão bom quanto falam as más línguas?

Comment: Desculpe @Renan eu editei a pergunta após você ter comentado algo e agora não existe mais a citação que você fez.

Answer (score 2):

## Justificativa

De forma nativa, o **jQuery** e o **Bootstrap** por si só não possuem animações que possam ser realizadas apenas ao incluir uma classe, porém há um CSS chamado [Animate](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) que permite que você realize esse tipo de animação apenas incluindo a classe dessa forma que você deseja.

## Exemplo

Segue [o exemplo que eu criei no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4td822m5/) com as animações rodando normalmente, após eu ter incluido o Animate.

#### Observações

Para incluir o animate no seu projeto basta incluir a CDN:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
```

> *Este link pode estar desatualizado, portanto sugiro que busque o CDN direto da* [página do github do Animate](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)